# Rôle of smooth structure

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

A central problem of interest in topology is the calculation of $\pi_n(S^m)$ and the classification of manifolds in general. In 1961 Kervaire constructed a manifold that does not admit a smooth structure.

What is the significance of smooth structures for computing $\pi_n(S^m)$? If there is no relation for homotopy groups of $S^m$, is there any information about $\pi_n (M^m)$ ($M^m$ an $m$-manifold) contained in the knowledge of whether $M^m$ does or does not admit a differentiable structure? What can be deduced about homotopy groups from the (non-)existence of smooth structures?

Comment: A good first place to look is the wikipedia page for the generalised Poincare conjeture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture which says that, in large enough dimensions, if an $n$-manifold is homotopy equivalent to the $n$-sphere, then it is homeomorphic to $S^n$ but not necessarily diffeomorphic. The latter class are known as the 'exotic' spheres.

Comment: @DanielRust Does this not just say that one can use the Kervaire invariant to prove that there exist exotic spheres? In this case my question would be: how does this help to find $\pi_n(S^m)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wikipedia page on [exotic spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere) is relevant. (I am not in my office, so I don't have better references handy.) If one denotes the group of exotic spheres in dimension $n$ by $\Theta_n$, there is a certain quotient group $\Theta_n/\mathrm{bP}_{n+1}$ by spheres which bound parallelizable $(n+1)$-manifolds. Then there is an injective map
$$\Theta_n/\mathrm{bP}_{n+1}\to \pi^s_n/\mathrm{im}(J)$$
where $\pi_n^S$ is the $n$th stable homotopy group of spheres and $J$ is the so-called $J$-homomorphism. By recent deep work on the Kervaire invariant problem, the above map is an isomorphism, except possibly when $n=126$, where it may have index $2$.

I have a feeling I may be summarizing what you already know, and maybe you are asking for the details of the map above?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the isomorphism result?

Comment: @DanielRust: just Wikipedia for now. I'll try digging up better references when I am in my office on Monday.

Comment: Ok thanks. It sounds like a very interesting result.

Comment: @DanielRust: Ravenel's webpage has a lot of resources, including a link to several talks he has given that give a lot of background. http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/kervaire.html

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Then this means that $\pi_{n+k}(S^n)$ is known for all $k,n$ except $k=126$?

Comment: No, just that it is isomorphic to the groups of exotic spheres modulo $bP$. The new thing that Hopkins et al proved is that the elements that might not come from spheres (the Kervaire invariant 1 elements) do not exist.